# what is the workable procedure for upgrading magento ce 2.3.x to 2.4.x

Tags: magento2

Due to the deprecation of composer 1 and EOL of magento 2.3.x, I am tempted to consider the upgrade magento from existing 2.3 to latest.

I did research and found not many guidance for upgrade but nothing work. Could you share your experience?

I came across many conflict or version not satisfiable ( composer, php version and modules ) on the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to upgrade your composer version, PHP version, Mysql version, Elasticsearch, and others you are using in your Magento website.

To find compatibility [Click here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html)

**After upgrading versions:**

You need to take backups of the database, app, lib, setup, composer.json, composer.lock, and vendor.

Now next step is to upgrade Magento version from 2.3.x to 2.4.5 (which is the latest for now).

Also, you need to change the `catalog search Engine to Elasticsearch as Mysql is deprecated in Magento 2.4.3 and above versions.`

**Using below command:**

```
php bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine elasticsearch7
```

**Run below commands:**

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5 --no-update

composer update
```

Then run basic commands like, `setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, s:s:d, c:f`

Magento will give you errors for custom modules, custom themes, and also for the modules you override.

You need to make it compatible with `PHP 8.1` and issues related to HTML files.

After running all the commands successfully. Test all the Magento websites thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Before proceeding you need to update the PHP version (8.1), MySQL version and Composer version.
Then after, do the following steps,

```
Take DB backup of site  
cp composer.json composer.json.bakup
cp composer.lock _composer.lock.bakup
cp .htaccess .htaccess_bakup 
cp pub/.htaccess pub/.htaccess_bakup
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.5 --no-update
composer update
```

Change the catalog search engine to Elasticsearch7 using the following command.

```
php bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine elasticsearch7
```

After executing the above commands, make changes in the module as an error appears during the di compile. Test all the Magento websites thoroughly after running all the commands.